# JPA mapping for multiple fields mapped to same foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have 2 tables, let say table A and table B.
I have to create 3 fields in A having a foreign key relationship with primaryId of B(nullable=true).

So to create one row in A, we must have 3 rows in B. All these 3 primaryKey of B will be inserted in 3 fields of A.

Example:

```
A fields are:
  id(Primary)
  DepartmentName1Id
  DepartmentName2Id
  DepartmentName3Id

B fields are:
  id(Primary)
  departmentName
  departmentAddress
  departmentPin
```

Here in above example `DepartmentName1Id`, `DepartmentName2Id`, `DepartmentName3Id` will hold different B ids(Primary). It can be null, but if it is not then there must be an entry for it in B.

How to create a JPA mapping relationship between these table A and B via Entity classes.

Comment: You are invited to read my posts about JPA. The articles are in spanish but is to easy understand: http://aquiseprograma.co/category/jpa/

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of your question. Is id only the primary key? or are you using composite primary key composed of id, department name, address and pin? What do you actually mean by this 'So to create one row in A, we must have 3 rows in B'? Can you show sample table containing data to illustrate the relationship bet. these 2 entities?

Answer (score 1):

What you have described is just:

```
@Entity
public class A {
  @Id
  Integer id;
  @OneToOne
  B DepartmentName1Id;
  @OneToOne
  B DepartmentName2Id;
  @OneToOne
  B DepartmentName3Id;
}

@Entity
public class B {
  @Id
  Integer id;
  String departmentName;
  String departmentAddress;
  String departmentPin;
}
```